# Is thare in STL or BOOST map like container with find and pop operation?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, dictionary, std

I want my map to be searchable and I want to be capable to kick out from it elements that were inserted into it longest time ago (with api like `map.remove(map.get_iterator_to_oldest_inserted_element())` ) like mix of queqe and map.. Is there any such container in STL or Boost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) using the `ordered_unique` and `sequence` indices, as in this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

// Element type to store in container
struct Element
{
    std::string key;
    int value;

    Element(const std::string& key, int value) : key(key), value(value) {}
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

// Boost multi_index container
typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    Element,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique< bmi::member<Element,std::string,&Element::key> >,
        bmi::sequenced<> >
    >
    MyContainer;

typedef MyContainer::nth_index<1>::type BySequence;

// Helper function that returns a sequence view of the container.
BySequence& bySequence(MyContainer& container) {return container.get<1>();}

int main()
{
    MyContainer container;

    // Access container by sequence. Push back elements.
    BySequence& sequence = bySequence(container);
    sequence.push_back(Element("one", 1));
    sequence.push_back(Element("two", 2));
    sequence.push_back(Element("three", 3));

    // Access container by key. Find an element.
    // By default the container is accessed as nth_index<0>
    MyContainer::const_iterator it = container.find("two");
    if (it != container.end())
        std::cout << it->value << "\n";

    // Access container by sequence. Pop elements in a FIFO manner,
    while (!sequence.empty())
    {
        std::cout << sequence.front().value << "\n";
        sequence.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a [boost multi-index container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to do this.

However, I have trouble understanding multi-index containers.  I think it would be easier to roll my own class that has as members a `std::queue` and a `std::map`, and manage it myself.

Comment: That would duplicate data unnecessarily -- MultiIndex doesn't duplicate data, but has you specify non-intrusive accessors instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that in boost and stl, but you can make a hybrid one yourself:

```
map<Key, Value> Map;
deque<Key> Queue;

void insert(const Key &k, const Value &v)
{
    Map[k] = v;
    Queue.push_back(k);
}
void pop_front()
{
    const Key &k = Queue.front();
    Map.erase(k);
    Queue.pop_front();
}
```

Comment: So I try to follow your sugestion.. but I see a littel problem in eraizing elements by key... I described it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705222/is-it-possible-to-remove-queue-element-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

Boost::bimap can be used to create a unidirectionnal map using a list-based relation set.

```
typedef bimap<set_of<A>, unconstrained_set_of<B>, list_of_relation> custom_map_type;

custom_map_type map;

map.push_back(custom_map_type::value_type(A(), B()));

// delete the front of the list (the first inserted element if only using push_back)
map.pop_front(); 

// otherwise, set.right behave a lot like a std::map<A,B>, with minor changes.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want to find the oldest (or newest -- or more generally the least/greatest by some specified criteria, and be able to remove that element), then a `priority_queue` will do the job.